# Heroku + Node.js crashing on start

Tags: javascript, heroku, graphql, koa, apollo-server

I'm aiming to create an GraphQL API for my website, with Koa and Apollo. When I start the app on heroku, it stops after 1 minute, because it can't bind to $PORT : `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`.
Everything works on local, and I followed the steps on [heroku](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error), but there's nothing to do, it doesnt change anything, here is my code :

```js
import koa from 'koa';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-koa';

        const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema: schema,
        });

        const app = new koa();

        this.server = server
        this.server.applyMiddleware({ app });
        this.app = app;
        this.server = server;
        this.app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

So what could be the cause of this error, and how could I solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any other errors from heroku console?

Comment: Mh yes, here is what I get when I type [`heroku logs`](https://pastebin.com/C4DRbcbU)

Comment: Are koa, graphql, and apollo installed? Do you get the same error if you replace the code for code for express? Have you successfully been able to launch the server on a local machine?

Comment: Yes, they were installed, and everything worked fine on my machine. It's not crashing anymore with express, thank you.

Comment: That suggests that there's an issue with just apollo/koa/etc. Do you still need apollo?

Comment: Yes, it permits me to use GraphQL.